# context menu not working with two fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, contextmenu, long-press

I have two fragments A and B, both of them have a listview, and extends from a base fragment C. Actually A and B extends the listview control from C.

I registed context menu in C in oder to implement a long press feature.

Now when I long press fragment A or B, the context menu can show as expected. Also when I was in fragment A, the context menu can work as excepted as well.

But we I navigate to Fragment B, long press the list,  the `onContextItemSelected` method never got called.

I did it like below.
First, register the context menu in `onActivityCreated` in Fragment C.

```
registerForContextMenu(transferTasksList);
```

Second, set layout and draw the menu in Fragment C.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    android.view.MenuInflater inflater = mActivity.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.upload_task_menu, menu);

    ListView listView = (ListView)v;
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    TransferTaskInfo taskInfo = (TransferTaskInfo)listView.getItemAtPosition(info.position);

    android.view.MenuItem itemCancel = menu.findItem(R.id.cancel);
    android.view.MenuItem itemRetry = menu.findItem(R.id.retry);
    android.view.MenuItem itemRemove = menu.findItem(R.id.remove);
    android.view.MenuItem itemRemoveAllCancelled = menu.findItem(R.id.remove_all_cancelled);
    android.view.MenuItem itemRemoveAllFinished = menu.findItem(R.id.remove_all_finished);

    itemCancel.setVisible(false);
    itemRetry.setVisible(false);
    itemRemove.setVisible(false);
    itemRemoveAllCancelled.setVisible(false);
    itemRemoveAllFinished.setVisible(false);

    switch (taskInfo.state) {
        case INIT:
            itemCancel.setVisible(true);
            break;
        case TRANSFERRING:
            itemCancel.setVisible(true);
            break;
        case CANCELLED:
            itemRetry.setVisible(true);
            itemRemove.setVisible(true);
            itemRemoveAllCancelled.setVisible(true);
            break;
        case FAILED:
            itemRetry.setVisible(true);
            itemRemove.setVisible(true);
            break;
        case FINISHED:
            itemRemove.setVisible(true);
            itemRemoveAllFinished.setVisible(true);
            break;
    }
}
```

Third, catch click event by abstract method `doContextItemSelected` in Fragment C.

```
@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        TransferService txService = mActivity.getTransferService();

        if (txService == null) {
            return false;
        }

        ListView listView = transferTasksList;
        TransferTaskInfo taskInfo = (TransferTaskInfo)listView.getItemAtPosition(info.position);
        TransferManager.TaskState state = taskInfo.state;
        int taskID = taskInfo.taskID;

        boolean needRefresh = doContextItemSelected(item, taskID, state);

        if (needRefresh) {
            refreshView();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and I implemented the abstract method is A and B like this.

```
@Override
boolean doContextItemSelected(MenuItem item, int taskID, TransferManager.TaskState state) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.cancel:
            if (state == TransferManager.TaskState.INIT || state == TransferManager.TaskState.TRANSFERRING) {
                mActivity.getTransferService().cancelUploadTask(taskID);
                return true;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.retry:
            if (state == TransferManager.TaskState.FAILED || state == TransferManager.TaskState.CANCELLED) {
                mActivity.getTransferService().retryUploadTask(taskID);
                return true;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.remove:
            if (state == TransferManager.TaskState.FINISHED ||
                    state == TransferManager.TaskState.FAILED ||
                    state == TransferManager.TaskState.CANCELLED) {
                mActivity.getTransferService().removeUploadTask(taskID);
                return true;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.remove_all_cancelled:
            if (state == TransferManager.TaskState.CANCELLED) {
                mActivity.getTransferService().removeAllUploadTasksByState(TransferManager.TaskState.CANCELLED);
                return true;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.remove_all_finished:
            if (state == TransferManager.TaskState.FINISHED) {
                mActivity.getTransferService().removeAllUploadTasksByState(TransferManager.TaskState.FINISHED);
                return true;
            }
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It works just fine in fragment A, when I long press fragment B, it can popup the menu which is fine, but when I choose menu item, it crashed.

the crash log is.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at com.seafile.seadroid2.ui.adapter.TransferTasksAdapter.getItem(TransferTasksAdapter.java:131)
        at com.seafile.seadroid2.ui.adapter.TransferTasksAdapter.getItem(TransferTasksAdapter.java:32)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.getItemAtPosition(AdapterView.java:764)
        at com.seafile.seadroid2.ui.fragment.TransferTaskFragment.onContextItemSelected(TransferTaskFragment.java:186)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performContextItemSelected(Fragment.java:1593)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchContextItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:2006)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:370)
        at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:210)
```

---

**UPDATE**

> The current value of the user-visible hint on this fragment.

In order to solve the issue, add the condition in one of your Fragment like below.

```
@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
        if (getUserVisibleHint()) {
            //TODO something when item was selected

            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: the menu is not your problem, your problem is here `TransferTasksAdapter.java:131`

Comment: yes, exactly. But when I click the context menu item, it always goes to fragment A even when I am in fragment B. and I fond the error caused by `listView.getItemAtPosition(info.position);` so do you know how to do something like, "i am in fragment B, get data type from B\`s adapter" because i always use A\`s.

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the same problem. But I did't write the code exactly same as you. I have two fragments in one activity (these two fragments don't extend from the same ancestor), say fragment A and fragment B. (in main_activity.xml fragment A is above fragment B, so in logcat, fragment A is always created before fragment B, I got this info from insert Log.d(...) in all callable functions in fragment A and fragment B)

There is a ListView in fragment A, there is a GridView in fragment B.
I called registerForContextMenu(...) in fragment onCreateView(..) callback, I also override onCreateContextMenu(..) and onContextItemSelected in fragment A.
I did the same thing in fragment B.
Now the problem cames:

1.
When I long click item(in the gridview) in fragment B, onCreateContextMenu of fragment B is called(I got this from log info), then I select item in the pop up context menu, strange enough, onContextItemSelected of fragment A is called.
(Since context menu item in fragment B is not same with context menu item in fragment A, sometimes the whole app crashed, sometimes nothing happened)

2.
When I long click item(in the list view) in fragment A, onCreateContextMenu of fragment A is called, then I select context item, onContextItemSelected of fragment A is called.

So, in total, fragment A is works, fragment B is not work. I found in order to solve this problem, we should do more stuff in onContextItemSelected in fragment A

```
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuItem.getMenuInfo();
        try {
            int position = info.position;
            final EditText et = (EditText) mListView.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.edittext);
            final String name = et.getText().toString();
            Log.d(TAG, "haha: " + name);
            switch(menuItem.getItemId()){
                case R.id.delete:
                    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mActivity);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                    editor.remove(name);
                    editor.commit();
                    notifyDataSetChange();
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The idea is return false from onContextItemSelected from fragment A when you find that the context item selected is not targeted to fragment A, then onContextItemSelected in fragment B will be called.

Comment: I have updated the question with a solution, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I had the same issue exactly, and your solution works! in my case there was a listview in each instance of the fragment and I called registerForContextMenu on both. As you mentioned - OnCreateContextMenu was called on the correct fragment but the OnContextMenuItemSelected was called on the wrong one!

Answer (score 0):

Please sort item using Trick below
Add this in every class you use in fragment

```
@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


 if(item.getTitle() == "Tittle you given to menu") {

// do somthing

}


}
```